# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null error when onmouseover

Tags: jquery, tooltip

DIV is like that

```
<div onmouseover="showTrackInfo(<?php echo $info['ID']; ?>);" id="pl_table_div_<?php echo $info['ID']; ?>">
```

JS is

```
function showTrackInfo(a) {
Tipped.create("#pl_table_div_"+a, 'test', {
      skin: "light",
      maxWidth: 400,
      fixed: true,
      hook: "middleleft"
   });
}
```

Where could i be wrong ?

Comment: Please post your rendered html. We have to make assumptions about what your php executes as... and it is bad to make assumptions when debugging.

Comment: php works good at render, it is like <div onmouseover="showTrackInfo(6577);" id="pl_table_div_6577">